# How to search for a string in cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

Let's say I have the cell array

```
strs = {'HA' 'KU' 'LA' 'MA' 'TATA'}
```

What should I do if I want to find the index of `'KU'`?

Comment: Note that the current top answer is quite outdated. Make sure to also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9433684/983722).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I guess the following code could do the trick:

```
strs = {'HA' 'KU' 'LA' 'MA' 'TATA'}
ind=find(ismember(strs,'KU'))
```

This returns

```
ans = 
     2
```

Comment: Keep in mind this generic solution is good because it works for multiple data types, but it only works for exact matches.  If you need a case-insensitive match, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9433112/44737.  If you need to match something more complex like a regex or a field in a structure, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061808/44737

Comment: ismember is a little more clunky and can get updated with newer versions.  I feel more safer with str based functions like strcmpi, etc.

Comment: Works in Octave, too

Answer (score 90):

```
>> strs = {'HA' 'KU' 'LA' 'MA' 'TATA'};
>> tic; ind=find(ismember(strs,'KU')); toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.001976 seconds.

```
>> tic; find(strcmp('KU', strs)); toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.000014 seconds.

SO, clearly `strcmp('KU', strs)` takes much lesser time than `ismember(strs,'KU')`

Comment: Great! Your solution should be the top one!

Comment: Yes I agree, this is the best solution, however its just a comparison between andreys and vidars solutions. So actually andrey should get it.

Comment: Actually, it should be pointed out that this method doesn't work if you are comparing two arrays of different size (i.e. if instead of 'KU' on the left side, you have an array of strings). Vidar's solution does work in that case (quite nicely), so is more general.

Comment: @pankaj : How does this compare to making a Map of String->Indices and then getting index by doing a map lookup? Asking perf wise.

Answer (score 41):

Since 2011a, the recommended way is:

```
booleanIndex = strcmp('KU', strs)
```

If you want to get the integer index (which you often don't need), you can use:

```
integerIndex = find(booleanIndex);
```

`strfind` is deprecated, so try not to use it.

Answer (score 25):

I see that everybody missed the most important flaw in your code:

```
strs = {'HA' 'KU' 'LA' 'MA' 'TATA'}
```

should be:

```
strs = {'HA' 'KU' 'NA' 'MA' 'TATA'}
```

or

```
strs = {'HAKUNA' 'MATATA'}
```

Now if you stick to using

```
ind=find(ismember(strs,'KU'))
```

You'll have [no worries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakuna_matata) :).

Comment: I was about to edit the original question but saw too many answers :)

Answer (score 13):

Other answers are probably simpler for this case, but for completeness I thought I would add the use of cellfun with an anonymous function

```
indices = find(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,'KU'), strs))
```

which has the advantage that you can easily make it case insensitive or use it in cases where you have cell array of structures:

```
indices = find(cellfun(@(x) strcmpi(x.stringfield,'KU'), strs))
```

Answer (score 6):

Most shortest code:

```
strs = {'HA' 'KU' 'LA' 'MA' 'TATA'};
[~,ind]=ismember('KU', strs)
```

But it returns only first position in `strs`. If element not found then `ind=0`.

Answer (score 5):

The strcmp and strcmpi functions are the most direct way to do this. They search through arrays.

```
strs = {'HA' 'KU' 'LA' 'MA' 'TATA'}
ix = find(strcmp(strs, 'KU'))
```

Answer (score -2):

did you try

```
indices = Find(strs, 'KU')
```

see [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html)

alternatively,

```
indices = strfind(strs, 'KU');
```

should also work if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I have tried find but since the array is cell array so MATLAB returns me some errors... But the function strfind seems working, thanks!