# Matlab, find string in cell

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I want to find the string in cell. I use this code but i receive an error. Is there any other method?a is a cell array and b is an element of cell matrix.

```
b(1,1)='kkkkk'

d=strfind(a,b(1,1));
```

but when I used the following code it worked.

```
d=strfind(a,'kkkkk');
```

any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, is `b` a cell matrix itself?

Comment: My old answer? Okay then... thought it was wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search for a string in cell array in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab)

Comment: @EitanT It is not the same problem as u see in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get and set the contents of a cell, use `{}` instead of `()`.

```
b{1,1}='kkkkk' 

d=strfind(a,b{1,1}));
```