# Matlab - vectorized way to indices in cell array equal string

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, cell-array

I have a 435x1 cell array whose elements are either 'y', 'n', or '?'. I want to find which indices are equal to 'y'.

With normal arrays, I just use the find function. But I can't use that with cell arrays because eq is not defined for type cell.

I think I can go through each element and do

```
for index=1:size(cell_array,1)
    if cell_array{index} == 'y'
        %add index to some array of indices
    end
end
```

But is there a vectorized way to go through the array and find indices contain elements that are equal to 'y'? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search for a string in cell array in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab)

Comment: @EitanT - I think Sterling was most interested in the `[cell_array{:}]=='y'` bit, which was not a possible solution for the other question, so `find` could be used in the familiar way with `eq`.  It's much the same functionally, I'll admit.

Answer (score 5):

Since you know each cell will contain a single character you can concatenate all the cell elements and do a single vectorized test:

```
find([cell_array{:}]=='y')
```

Possibly the most straightforward way is just to use `strcmp`, which can accept a cell array as the second argument:

```
find(strcmp('y',cell_array))
```

Comment: More precisely, you'd want `find(strcmp('y',cell_array))`, so that you'd get the indices of the 'y' values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll clarify that you need `find` around `strcmp`.

Comment: +1 The second method is more general, as it doesn't require single-chracter strings