# MATLAB : Contingency Table

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of the following type :

```
 datABC =
           [45]  [67]  'A'
           [34]  [44]  'A'
           [11]  [84]  'A'
           [23]  [68]  'A'
           [34]  [44]  'B'
           [30]  [94]  'B'
           [304]  [414]  'C'
           [78]  [110]  'C'
           [34]  [120]  'C'
```

Now i have to calculate the number of observations and mean of first and second column according to `A`, `B` & `C`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must restrain my self... do... not... post... answer.

Comment: a hint... cellfun is one way to do this

Comment: This will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab

Comment: @tmpearce I have thought of the command `crosstab` and `hist` . But somehow i couldn't able.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as the floodgates are opened, I might as well throw in my two cents.

A solution with a loop works well, but you can also eliminate loops, at the expense of readability. First, you can get the unique values in the last column with `unique`:

```
stringKeys = unique(datABC(:,3))'
```

Then you can use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to count the occurrences of each key:

```
memberFun = @(x) ismember(datABC(:,3),x);
keyOccurrences = cellfun(@(x) nnz(memberFun(x)),stringKeys)
```

To compute the mean of the corresponding data for each of the first two columns, you can again use `cellfun` with non-uniform outputs:

```
colMeanFun = @(x) mean(reshape([datABC{memberFun(x),1:2}],[],2),1);
colMeans = cellfun(colMeanFun,stringKeys,'UniformOutput',false);
colMeans = vertcat(colMeans{:})
```

Also have a look ate [`strcmpmi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html), which can be used in place of `ismember` but will ignore case.

**Test data**:

```
datABC = {[45]  [67]  'A'; [34]  [44]  'A'; [11]  [84]  'A'; ...
          [23]  [68]  'A'; [34]  [44]  'B'; [30]  [94]  'B'; ...
          [304] [414] 'C'; [78]  [110] 'C'; [34]  [120] 'C'}; % 9-by-3
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a job for `accumarray`:

```
[categories ii jj] = unique(dataABC(:,3));
num = histc(jj,1:max(jj));
mean1 = accumarray(jj, cell2mat(dataABC(:,1)), [], @mean);
mean2 = accumarray(jj, cell2mat(dataABC(:,2)), [], @mean);
```

Example:

```
>> dataABC{4,2}

dataABC = 

    [1]    [10]    'A' 
    [2]    [-5]    'B' 
    [3]    [15]    'A' 
    [4]    [40]    'CC'
```

gives

```
categories = 

    'A'
    'B'
    'CC'

>> num

num =

     2
     1
     1

>> mean1

mean1 =

     2
     2
     4

>> mean2

mean2 =

   12.5000
   -5.0000
   40.0000
```

Comment: @chappjc I couldn't restrain like you did!

Comment: @chappjc Hey, in the end you didn't either!

Comment: I only partially restrained - I typed my answer, deleted it, and waited for others to answer.  :D  I figure the question is useful to others, so why not answer after a bit of a wait.

Comment: Seriously, `unique` and `accumarray` work very well together.  When you realize that the third output of `unique` essentially provides an integer key for each unique value, the use of `accumarray` follows naturally. +1

Comment: @chappjc `accumarray` addicts!!

Answer (score 1):

Get comfortable with [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

```
for x = unique(datABC(:,3))'
    idx = strcmp(x, datABC(:, 3));
    disp([x{1} ': ' num2str(sum(idx)) ' observations'])
    disp(mean(cell2mat(datABC(idx, 1:2))))
end
```