# How to locate a str in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, indexing

I'm a newbie to Matlab and have a question about str locating:

`A = ['abc','de','fghij','something','another'];`

Then how can I get `3` if I use `strfind(A,'fghij')`?

Thanks.

Comment: After converting `A` to a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html) (due to the semantics of [strings in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html), I'd suggest the [second highest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18649852/3121310) with `strcmp` since it is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I understand your question, but if you are wondering why the value is 3 instead of 2 it is because matlab (unlike most languages you may be used to) indexes arrays starting at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: oh...I know Matlab is different with C/Java in indexing. My question is how to find the index. Since Mablab uses cells of strings, and I'm not quite familiar with such "data structures", I cannot figure how to locate a string....still thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TroyHaskin ! I find the answer in another post~

`idx=find(ismemeber(A,'fghij'))` is what I want.

Comment: If the duplicate answered your question, you should select the "That solved my problem!" button at the top of your question in the duplicate dialogue.